# Power Bi Json Theme - Pivot Table Row Subtotal Formatting not working

Tags: json, powerbi, pivot-table, themes

I am creating a json Theme file for my company and I am stuck on the matrix table. It just doesnt take the inputs for row subtotals.

Here's the code:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "pivotTable": {
        "*": {
            "stylePreset": [
                {
                    "name": "Default"
                }
            ],
            "grid": [
                {
                    "gridVertical": false,
                    "gridHorizontal": false,
                    "rowPadding": 4,
                    "outlineWeight": 2,
                    "textSize": 10
                }
            ],
            "columnHeaders": [
                {
                    "fontColor": {
                        "solid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff"
                        }
                    },
                    "backColor": {
                        "solid": {
                            "color": "#142640"
                        }
                    },
                    "outline": "None",
                    "outlineColor": {
                        "solid": {
                          "color": "#0e1622"
                        }
                    },
                    "outlineWeight": 1,
                    "autoSizeColumnWidth": true,
                    "fontFamily": "Calibri",
                    "fontSize": 10,
                    "bold": true,
                    "alignment": "Left",
                    "titleAlignment": "Left",
                    "wordWrap": true
                }
            ],
            "rowHeaders": [
                {
                    "fontColor": {
                        "solid": {
                            "color": "#0e1622"
                        }
                    },
                    "outline": "RightOnly",
                    "outlineColor": {
                        "solid": {
                          "color": "#0e1622"
                        }
                    },
                    "outlineWeight": 1,
                    "stepped": true,
                    "steppedLayoutIndentation": 10,
                    "wordWrap": true,
                    "fontFamily": "Calibri",
                    "fontSize": 10,
                    "alignment": "Left",
                    "showExpandCollapseButtons": true
                }
            ],
            "values": [
                {
                    "fontColorPrimary": {
                        "solid": {
                            "color": "#0e1622"
                        }
                    },
                    "backColorPrimary": {
                        "solid": {
                            "color": "#ffffff"
                        }
                    },
                    "fontColorSecondary": {
                        "solid": {
                            "color": "#0e1622"
                        }
                    },
                    "backColorSecondary": {
                        "solid": {
                            "color": "#F4F4F4"
                        }
                    },
                    "bandedRowHeaders": true,
                    "valuesOnRow": true,
                    "wordWrap": true,
                    "fontFamily": "Calibri",
                    "fontSize": 10
                }
            ],
            "subTotals": [
                {
                    "rowSubtotals": true,
                    "columnSubtotals": true,
                    "fontColor": {
                        "solid": {
                            "color": "#0e1622"
                        }
                    },
                    "fontFamily": "Calibri",
                    "fontSize": 10,
                    "applyToHeaders": true,
                    "applyToLabels": true
                }
            ],
            "rowTotal": [
                {
                    "fontColor": {
                        "solid": {
                            "color": "#0e1622"
                        }
                    },
                    "fontFamily": "Calibri",
                    "fontSize": 10,
                    "applyToHeaders": true
                }
            ],
            "columnTotal": [
                {
                    "fontColor": {
                        "solid": {
                            "color": "#0e1622"
                        }
                    },
                    "fontFamily": "Calibri",
                    "applyToHeaders": true,
                    "fontSize": 10
                }
            ],         
            "totals": [
                {
                    "fontColor": {
                        "solid": {
                            "color": "#0e1622"
                        }
                    },
                    "fontFamily": "Calibri",
                    "bold": true,
                    "applyToHeaders": true,
                    "applyToLabels": true,
                    "fontSize": 10
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When I load it into the report there's these two that don't do what I want (see attached pics):

- **Column grand total** needs to be Calibri 10, apply to labels true
- **Row subtotals** needs to also be Calibri 10,apply to labels true

I also included a pic of current vs desired. Please let me know what I did wrong!
[Column Grand Total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XK11.png), [Row Subtotals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmRvm.png), [Current vs desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYVZq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it myself after trying different stuff. I had to go to the subtotals section and define font for rowsubtotals and columnsubtotals separately., like so:

```
"rowSubtotals": true,
"fontFamilyrowSubtotals": "Calibri",
"fontSizerowSubtotals": 10,
"columnSubtotals": true,
"fontFamilycolumnSubtotals": "Calibri",
"fontSizecolumnSubtotals": 10
```

This is the whole solution:

```
{
    "name": "MatrixTemplate",
    "visualStyles": {
        "pivotTable": {
            "*": {
                    "stylePreset":[{
                                "name":"Default"
                            }],
                    "grid": [{
                    "gridVertical": false,
                    "gridVerticalColor": { "solid": { "color": "#F4F4F4"}},
                    "gridVerticalWeight": 2,
                    "gridHorizontal": false,
                    "gridHorizontalColor": { "solid": { "color": "#F4F4F4"}},
                    "gridHorizontalWeight": 2,
                    "rowPadding": 4,
                    "outlineColor": { "solid": { "color": "#F4F4F4"}},
                    "outlineWeight": 2,
                    "textSize": 10,
                    "imageHeight": 100
                }],
                "columnHeaders": [{
                    "fontColor": { "solid": { "color": "#ffffff"}},
                    "backColor": { "solid": { "color": "#142640"}},
                    "autoSizeColumnWidth": true,
                    "fontFamily": "Calibri",
                    "fontSize": 10,
                    "bold": true,
                    "alignment": "Left",
                    "titleAlignment": "Left",
                    "urlIcon": true,
                    "wordWrap": true
                }],
                "rowHeaders": [{
                    "fontColor": { "solid": { "color": "#0e1622"}},
                    "backColor": { "solid": { "color": "#ffffff"}},
                    "outline": "Frame",
                    "outlineColor": { "solid": { "color": "#142640"}},
                    "outlineWeight": 1,
                    "stepped": true,
                    "steppedLayoutIndentation": 12,                 
                    "urlIcon": true,
                    "wordWrap": true,
                    "fontFamily": "Calibri",
                    "fontSize": 10,
                    "alignment": "Left", 
                    "showExpandCollapseButtons":true
                }],
                "values": [{
                    "fontColorPrimary": { "solid": { "color": "#0e1622"}},
                    "backColorPrimary": { "solid": { "color": "#ffffff"}},
                    "fontColorSecondary": { "solid": { "color": "#0e1622"}},
                    "backColorSecondary": { "solid": { "color": "#F4F4F4"}},
                    "bandedRowHeaders": true,
                    "valuesOnRow": true,
                    "outline": "Frame",
                    "urlIcon": true,
                    "wordWrap": true,
                    "fontFamily": "Calibri",
                    "fontSize": 10
                }],
                "subTotals": [{
                    "rowSubtotals": true,
                    "fontFamilyrowSubtotals": "Calibri",
                    "fontSizerowSubtotals": 10,
                    "columnSubtotals": true,
                    "fontFamilycolumnSubtotals": "Calibri",
                    "fontSizecolumnSubtotals": 10,
                    "applyToHeaders": true,
                    "perRowLevel": true,
                    "perColumnLevel": true                  
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```